# Add constant list to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list

Assuming I have a df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
```

All I want is to add a new column, `c`, with a constant list (for example: `[7,8,9,10]`).

When I try:

```
df['c']=[7,8,9,10]
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I tried to play also with `loc`, `at`, `ix` - but couldn't figure it out.

An ugly workaround I found is to do something like:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: [7,8,9,10])
```

But there must be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: It's difficult for a reason. Why do you need to store a list, let alone a list with the same exact information, in every row of your DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler way is:

```
df['c'] =  [[7,8,9,10]]*len(df)
```

result:

```
   a  b              c
0  1  4  [7, 8, 9, 10]
1  2  5  [7, 8, 9, 10]
2  3  6  [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

UPDATE:

To avoid problem of shallow copy of lists in each row (as @YOBEN_S described), use:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: [7,8,9,10], axis = 1)
```

Now it is possible to change for example only first element in column `c` of the first row by calling:

```
df.loc[0,'c'][0]='test'
```

```
   a  b                 c
0  1  4  [test, 8, 9, 10]
1  2  5     [7, 8, 9, 10]
2  3  6     [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: This is unsafe.

Comment: What unsafe means in this context? BTW I tried to find an alternative solution but failed. @YOBEN_S do You have more suitable answer?

Comment: Try df.loc[0,'c'][0]='test', you will all row changed ~

Comment: Yes, it seems there is a shallow copy problem. To avoid it can use `df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: [7,8,9,10], axis = 1)`. But is there a better approach than `lambda`?

Comment: I will do for loop

Answer (score 1):

This will add constant list to df

```
#df['c']=pd.Series([[7,8,9,10]]*len(df))
df=df.assign(c=pd.Series([[7,8,9,10]]*len(df)))



  a  b              c
0  1  4  [7, 8, 9, 10]
1  2  5  [7, 8, 9, 10]
2  3  6  [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This would add column to df using its index

```
df['c']=pd.Series([7,8,9,10])
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```